# Unable to make this list perform rstrip how I want it to

Tags: python

This is basically the problem-- my i.rstrip isn't working right. What did I do wrong?

code: http://pastebin.com/ST0aX399

The text file I am iterating over is:

```
10001 Vehicles
10002 Family & Community
10003 Real Estate
10004 Business & Industrial
10005 Beauty & Personal Care
10006 Occasions & Gifts
10009 Home & Garden
10010 Food & Groceries
10011 Health
10012 Finance
10013 Arts & Entertainment
10014 Sports & Fitness
10015 Hobbies & Leisure
10016 Jobs & Education
10017 Travel & Tourism
10019 Computers & Consumer Electronics
10020 Dining & Nightlife
10021 Apparel
10024 Motor Vehicles
10026 Vehicle Parts & Accessories
10027 Boats & Watercraft
10030 Baby, Parenting & Family
10031 Romance & Relationships
10032 Rental Listings
10039 Property Development
10040 Real Estate Agents & Brokerages
10042 Real Estate Listings
10047 Skin Care
10048 Tanning & Sun Care
10049 Spa & Medical Spa
10050 Anti-Aging
10052 Baby Care & Hygiene
10054 Make-Up & Cosmetics
10055 Hair Care
10057 Perfumes & Fragrances
10058 Shaving & Grooming
10060 Hygiene & Toiletries
10061 Face Care
10082 Food
10085 Health Conditions & Concerns
10086 Nutrition & Dieting
10087 Medical Devices, Equipment & Supplies
10088 Biotech & Pharmaceutical
10089 Pharmacy
10091 Health Care Services
10092 Financial Planning & Management
10093 Banking
10094 Money Transfer & Wire Services
10095 Investing
10096 Business Banking & Finance
10097 Credit & Lending
10098 Business News & Media
10099 Grants, Scholarships & Financial Aid
10102 Insurance
10103 TV & Video
10105 Entertainment Industry
10106 Humor & Jokes
10108 News, Media & Publications
10109 Music & Audio
10111 Events, Shows & Cultural Attractions
10112 Books & Literature
10113 Camping & Outdoor Recreation
10116 Sports Fan Gear & Apparel
10117 Boating & Water Recreation
10121 Sporting Goods
10123 Fitness
10127 Occult & Paranormal
10128 Cooking
10130 Pets
10132 Photo & Video
10135 Antiques & Collectibles
10137 Gambling
10141 Education & Training
10142 Accommodations
10144 Air Travel
10145 Tourist Attractions & Destinations
10146 Transportation & Excursions
10147 Last Minute Travel
10150 Specialty Travel
10151 Travel Booking Services
10153 Cruises & Cruise Services
10167 Consumer Electronics
10168 Computers
10169 Restaurants
10171 Jewelry
10176 Clothing
10177 Footwear
10182 Motorcycles
10185 Cars & Trucks
10209 Car Parts & Accessories
10235 Baby
10236 Parenting & Family
10273 Design & Engineering
10282 Building Construction & Maintenance
10294 Scientific Equipment & Services
10295 Energy & Utility
10296 Business Management Software
10299 Security Equipment & Services
10300 Office
10301 Food Service Industry
10302 Industrial Electronics
10306 Plant & Facility
10307 Commercial & Industrial Printing
10364 Cards & Greetings
10365 Gifts
10369 Weddings
10404 Home Improvement & Maintenance
10405 Home Decor & Interior Decorating
10406 Yard, Garden & Patio
10410 Kitchen & Dining
10412 Home Appliances
10413 Home Furniture
10432 Baked Goods & Bakery Items
10434 Baking Ingredients
10453 Smoking & Smoking Cessation
10454 Warts
10460 Vision
10473 Skin Conditions & Skin Health
10491 Diets & Diet Programs
10507 Alternative, Non-Western & Complementary Care
10508 Plastic & Cosmetic Surgery
10509 Laboratory Testing & Medical Diagnostic Services
10531 Real Estate Investments
10550 Vehicle Insurance
10557 TV Shows & Programs
10566 TV Broadcasting
10578 Travel Media & Publications
10653 Golf Equipment
10666 Fitness Classes & Instruction
10669 Personal Training
10671 Toys
10672 Games
10679 Recipes
10683 Pet Food & Supplies
10691 Digital Cameras
10746 Job Listings
10754 Standardized & Admissions Tests
10756 Reference Materials & Resources
10759 Vocational Training & Trade Schools
10763 Colleges, Universities & Post-Secondary Education
10769 Hotels, Motels & Resorts
10770 Vacation Rentals
10776 Luggage
10778 Airline Tickets, Fares & Flights
10872 Consumer Electronic Accessories
10873 Home Audio & Video
10876 Wireless Devices
10877 Portable Media Devices
10878 Telephony
10880 GPS
10881 Car Audio & Video
10883 Computer Hardware
10885 Software
10886 Computer Accessories
10889 Cuisines
10913 Underwear
11020 Baby Diapering & Toilet Training
11028 Maternity & New Parent
11093 Accounting & Auditing
11099 Office & Facilities Management
11141 Commercial & General Contracting
11270 Project Management Software
11284 HVAC
11287 Hardware Tools & Accessories
11339 Office Appliances
11368 Graphics & Multimedia Software
11491 Internet Service Plans
11493 Web Design & Development
11496 Social Networks & Online Communities
11504 Web Hosting
11511 Mobile Phone Plans
11669 Weight Loss Products
11710 Acne
11772 Vitamins & Supplements
11783 Cosmetic Surgery & Medical Spa Services
11813 Private Banking
11814 Online Banking
11816 Debit & Check Cards
11818 Fixed Deposit Accounts & Certificates
11819 Brokerages & Day Trading
11820 Investor Relations & Venture Capital
11824 Retirement Investments
11825 Spread Betting
11827 Securities
11828 Mutual Funds
11840 Unsecured Credit & Lending
11841 Loans
11842 Credit Cards
11870 Dining & Nightlife Reviews, Guides & Listings
11942 Online Games & Puzzles
11950 Video Games, Consoles & Accessories
11980 Pet Breeding
12066 Resorts
12067 Hotels
12143 Televisions
12161 Mobile Phones
12184 Computer Networking Devices
12187 Laptop Computers
12204 Internet Software & Web Goodies
12209 Business & Productivity Software
12240 Shirts, Tops & Blouses
12494 Medical Diagnostic Equipment & Monitoring Devices
12590 Power Tools
12864 Weight Loss Drugs & Medications
12865 Weight Loss Supplements
12950 401(K)s
12952 IRAs
12956 Commercial Lending
12957 Auto Financing
12960 Home Loans & Mortgages
12961 Personal Lending & Borrowing
12997 Massive Multiplayer Online Games
13094 Email & Messaging
13116 Jerseys & Knit Shirts
13283 Commercial Mortgages
13284 Auto Leasing
13286 Title Loans
13289 Interest Only Mortgages
13291 Government Mortgages
13292 Buy-To-Let Mortgages
13293 Fixed Rate Mortgages
13296 Home Equity Loans & Lines of Credit
13299 Home Refinancing Loans
13300 Payday & Emergency Loans
13301 Personal Loans & Lines of Credit
13377 Computer & Video Games
13381 Mobile Phones & Accessories
13388 Visual Art & Design
13417 Movies & Films
13418 Internet
13419 Phone Plans
13422 Body Art
13423 Guns & Firearms
13425 Fun & Trivia
13432 Translation
13459 Stocks
13464 Industrial Goods & Manufacturing
13469 Astrology & Horoscopes
13470 Psychics & Fortune Telling
13491 Chemical Industry
13493 Occasions
13530 Arts & Entertainment Awards
13536 Film & TV Industry
13566 Offbeat
13567 Edgy & Bizarre
13596 Photographic & Digital Arts
13605 Sports
13610 Baseball
13655 Vehicle Dealers
13656 Car Dealers
13657 Boat & Yacht Sales & Brokers
13658 Gardening
13714 Used Cars & Trucks
13725 Web Portals
13760 Cartoons
13768 Domain Names & Domain Name Registration
13780 Children's Clothing
13797 Building Materials & Supplies
```

Comment: Please explain (by editing the question) what "isn't working right" means.

Comment: Your linked code doesn't have a single call to `rstrip` in it.

Comment: I meant lstrip. Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip`, `lstrip` and `rstrip` return new string and strings are immutable. This said your `i` variable in loop after `i.lstrip()` is pointing at different place in memory and the list is intact. You have to construct new list like this

```
def makeList():
    lines = []
    with open('categories.txt', 'r') as file:
        for l in file:
            lines.append(l.lstrip('0123456789 '))
    return lines
```